# запуск CMake проекта на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, visual-studio-2019

Создал самый простой CMake-проект в VS2019, удалённо собрал на VB с Ubuntu, запустил, всё хорошо, всё работает. Как запускать исполняемый файл в самой Ubuntu и как он может быть назван? Исполняемых файлов в каталоге с проектом нет, но на студии он же запускается. 
Может это Makefile? Если так, то как его запустить?

Единственное что сделал:

$make

[100%] Build target CMakeProject1

Comment: Может здесь будет что-то полезное? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/CPackDeb.html

Comment: Описание у вас конечно... Ну, для начала, где вы вызвали `make`? Что у вас там могло собраться, если вы не вызывали сам `cmake`? Каков ваш `CMakeLists.txt`? Отдельно хочу скзать про то, что вы, очевидно, даже в вижуалке толком не понимаете что делаете - для вас не понятно даже то, как вы запускаете ваш "проект". Так что вам бы азы подучить

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, да вы правы, толком не разобравшись я пошёл задавать не самые лучшие вопросы. На первый взгляд всё казалось очевидным. Как разберусь, я отвечу на свой же вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

исполняемый файл был всегда (в папке с Makefile), просто в проводнике он не отображался как исполняемый, через терминал он спокойно запускается.